# How to use the map in the array two-dimensional in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have an array two-dimensional, and I want to get the value `name`.

My State:

```js
this.state={
            func:[{id: 1, matric:'041810', name:"Jean", site:'Pasteur', manager:"Abel", endContract:'05/06/2018', 
coworks:[{id:10,name:'jean'}, {id:13, name:'jojo'}]}],
            valueMatricInput: '',
            coWorksArray: [],
            funcSelected: [],
            nameFunc: [],
        }
```

And where is `coworks`i want to get the attribute `name`.

My map for to get and given the array for array empty (`coWorksArray`):

```js
   this.setState({coWorks: this.state.funcSelected.map(name=>name.coworks)})
        console.log(this.state.coWorks)
```

And my code for to get the names:

```js
GetWorksTeste (){
        const {coWorks} = this.state;
            coWorks.map(function(cw){
                return (<li>{cw.name}</li>)
            })
        
    }
```

Someone would can help me ?

Comment: Jota, I am sorry to say that I do not understand what you are asking.  It may just be me, but an unclear question will probably not get answers that are useful to you.  Please edit to clearly state _specifically_ what problem you are encountering.

Comment: @AlexanderNied 
Thanks for the interest.

What I want is, to filter `coworks` and get the `name` attributes of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what You trying to achieve if u need to extract the value of name attribute from "coworks" the object,

In plain vanilla js, You can achieve same via

```
var result = this.state.func[0].coworks.map((obj) => {
    return obj.name;
});
```

the result var will hold the value of name attribute in an array of strings.

["jean", "jojo"]

Answer (score 0):

One can use  [`JS#Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
var {func : [firstObject ]} = state //spread into array of object.can be generalize

var {coworks} = firstObject; //spread to get coworks

coworks.map((cw)=>console.log(cw.name)); // loop it
```